# How to create start and end date from a year string

Tags: momentjs

I want to get the start and end dates of a particular year.

Something like
moment(2009).startOf('year') // Format: 2009-01-01 00:00
moment(2009).endOf('year') // Format: 2009-12-31 11:59

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
const start = moment([2009]).startOf('year').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM');
const end = moment([2009]).endOf('year').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM');
```